# Android EncryptedSharedPreferences Multi-process

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, encrypted-shared-preference

Has anyone implemented a multi-process EncryptedSharedPreferences? I couldn't find any google link to anything, nor could I find any StackOverflow posts regarding this.

I'm trying to use EncryptedSharedPreferences and find that unlike normal SharedPreferences with MULTI_MODE_PROCESS, its values don't get carried over between processes. And I can't find any doc that says how to init EncryptedSharedPreferences with MULTI_MODE_PROCESS. Can anyone please give me any leads?

I need to share a token between processes, and need some way to do this with EncryptedSharedPreferences.

Comment: Even in regular SharedPreferences MODE_MULTI_PROCESS don't work reliably, and recommends using a ContentProvider to expose your preferences across processes instead (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)

Comment: The implementation hard codes it to MODE_PRIVATE, so I am afraid you have to build your own IPC layer on top: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:security/security-crypto/src/main/java/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences.java;l=166;bpv=0